# How to make one page public, from Windows Authenticated web app?

Tags: .net, windows-authentication

I created a small, .NET 4.0/MVC, intranet app, with Windows Authentication. But my boss changed his mind and I have to make home page public, accessible by everybody, while keep the rest locked. How can I to do it?

Thanks for any help,
Afan

Answer (score 0):

An intranet by definition is only accessible by the users inside an organization. If you need to make the homepage accessible by all authenticated users and the rest (e.g. http://site/secret/ by certain group only then read about [role based authorization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx). For example, it can be done like this

```
<system.webServer> 
    <security> 
        <authorization> 
            <allow users="*" />
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization> 
    </security> 
</system.webServer> 
<location path="secret"> 
    <system.webServer> 
        <security> 
            <authorization> 
                <deny users="*" />
                <allow roles="DomainName\WindowsSecretGroup" />
            </authorization> 
        </security> 
    </system.webServer> 
</location>
```